# Find Current URL of .aspx Webpage w/ Drop-down Menu

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but I'd really appreciate the help.

I'm trying to scrape some data and am using `wget` to download the page source data from the desired webpage. Unfortunately, I'm having some trouble as the webpage contains a drop-down menu. When I access the desired webpage via the drop-down menu, the contents of the webpage change, but the URL stays the same. Is there a way to find the URL of the current page rather than the default page? I am on a Mac, so is there a solution possibly involving a command line tool?

The site I'm trying to scrape is password-protected, but I figured I'd post the default URL, which is http://media.nba.com/Stats/OfficialBoxScores.aspx

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: There doesn't need to be another url. Most likely selecting the page causes it to post back to the server. The server is then getting whatever the selected dropdownlist option is and using that to generate the page results. Urls don't have to change to alter the data.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So if that's the case, it sounds like I'd only be able to access the data from the default page. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. You can attempt to post back to the page and determine the form fields names and data it expects to get it to return varying data such as those based on a dropdown. Not saying to do anything that violates the EULA, just one possible way.